# What is causing white space in my mobile site?

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

I'm in the process of creating a responsive site. It is resizing properly, but I noticed, that when highlighting text on the page, as if I were going to copy it into my clipboard, it scrolls to the right revealing white space.

There is no scroll bar because I have implemented html{overflow-x:hidden} in my stylesheet, so this isn't like the other situations I've seen around the web. This only occurs at sizes less than 1024px.

I have set media query sizes, have styled accordingly, and again have hidden any overflow.

This site is not live right now, and my client is trying to keep things rather private, so my hands are tied with how much I can share.

What could I be missing that could be causing this white space to appear?

Comment: Can't say for sure without seeing any code. You can probably find out why by inspecting the page with firebug. Then hide each element until that extra space is gone so you know what's causing it. Start hiding with the biggest blocks and then drill down

Comment: You sir are a genius. I'm embarrassed I never thought of trial and error. I didn't realize that, in my stylesheet, some of the elements had varying widths or padding, which I'm guessing was a result of me experimenting and forgetting to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

put this in `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your margins and paddings are not overflowing and not set to 100%.
you can use chromes inspector or something to debug for that.